# How to show 2 digits after comma on CS-CART when decimals in currency set to 4?

Tags: php, cs-cart

For accurate VAT counting our e-shop set currency to show 4 digits after comma. How to show only 2 digits on store, but keep counting VAT when 4 digits set after comma in admin panel.
Now it shows something like this: €23.1621 , need to be €23.16

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the round() function?

```
echo round(price, 2);
```

Comment: Whenever you want to display your price. I can't see any code so it's hard for me to tell.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version.

In 4.1.x version you can try to modify the "smarty_modifier_format_price" function (**app/functions/smarty_plugins/modifier.format_price.php**)

Change this

```
$value = fn_format_rate_value($price, $number_type, $currency['decimals'], $currency['decimals_separator'], $currency['thousands_separator'], $currency['coefficient']);
```

By this

```
$value = fn_format_rate_value($price, $number_type, 2, $currency['decimals_separator'], $currency['thousands_separator'], $currency['coefficient']);
```